# Capturing Kafka offsets when writing with Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using Spark Structured streaming on Spark 2.2 to Stream Files from an HDFS directory to a Kafka Topic.  I would like to capture the Kafka offsets for the data I am writing to the topic.

I am using

```
val write = jsonDF
.writeStream.format("kafka")
.option("checkpointLocation", Config().getString(domain + ".kafkaCheckpoint"))
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Config().getString(domain + ".kafkaServer"))
.option("topic", Config().getString(domain + ".kafkaTopic"))
.start()
```

To write to Kafka.

When I utilize

```
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {
  override def onQueryStarted(queryStarted: QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
    println("Query started: " + queryStarted.id) 
  }
  override def onQueryTerminated(queryTerminated: QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
    println("Query terminated: " + queryTerminated.id)
  }
  override def onQueryProgress(queryProgress: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    println("Query made progress: " + queryProgress.progress)
  }
})
```

to capture the stream's progress information the information retrieved does not correlate with the offsets being created in Kafka.

I assume that this is because the information provided by the stream is really about the file stream I am utilizing and not related to what is written in Kafka.

Is there a way with Spark Structure Streaming to capture the offset information that is being generated when we write to Kafka?

Adding Example:
When I run data in from source 1 with three rows after just creating the topic I get:
Run 1: 
      Start Offset: null, End offset: {"logOffset":0}
      Start Offset: {"logOffset":0}, End offset: {"logOffset":0}

```
 Kafka Says:
 ruwe:2:1
 ruwe:1:1
 ruwe:0:1
```

Run 2;

```
  Start Offset: {"logOffset":0}, End offset: {"logOffset":1}
  Start Offset: {"logOffset":1}, End offset: {"logOffset":1}

 Kafka Says:
 ruwe:2:2
 ruwe:1:2
 ruwe:0:2
```

Run 3:

```
  Start Offset: {"logOffset":1}, End offset: {"logOffset":2}
  Start Offset: {"logOffset":2}, End offset: {"logOffset":2}

 Kafka Says:
 ruwe:2:3
 ruwe:1:3
 ruwe:0:3
```

I then ran data in with the same program from a different source and received

```
  Start Offset: null, End offset: {"logOffset":0}
  Start Offset: {"logOffset":0}, End offset: {"logOffset":0}

  and of course Kafka continued to increment
```

This indicates that Spark is reporting information that is based on the source

I would like to know what was created in the target.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way with Spark Structure Streaming to capture the offset
>   information that is being generated when we write to Kafka?

Yes, in `onQueryProgress`, you need to look at the `StreamingQueryProgress.sources` which is an `Array[SourceProgress]`. It has two strings, `startOffset` and `endOffset`, which are JSONs that you can parse:

```
sparkSession.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener {override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = ???

  override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    val source = event.progress.sources.headOption
    source.map(src => println(s"Start Offset: ${src.startOffset}, End offset: ${src.endOffset}"))
  }

  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = ()
})
```

The JSON has the following structure:

```
"startOffset" : {
  "topic-name" : {
    "0" : 1,
    "1" : 22,
    "2" : 419,
  }
},
"endOffset" : {
  "topic-name" : {
    "0" : 10,
    "1" : 100,
    "2" : 1000
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be reporting back offsets for the source not for the target (Kafka).  If I continue to run from the same source my numbers go up but when I run in data from a second source it reports back initial numbers indicating that these are not the Kafka Offsets that are being reported.

Comment: @SRuwe If you want target offsets, look into `SinkProgress.json`

Answer (score 1):

After reading the code for Spark Structure Streaming  Specifically the Kafka KafkaWriter, KafkaWriteTask and CachedKafkaProducer, Spark does not consume the offsets that are returned from the KafkaProducer in the callback.  The callback they define only captures exceptions.  Based on this I would say the in the current release 2.2 it cannot be done.

What information they provide is all around the source of the query not the target.